# How connect in Redis with Auth/Password NodeJs for AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, redis, aws-lambda, node-redis

I am making a lambda function for validations tokens in AWS Api Gateway. However, I need to connect with the redis with security, but ever fails with this config:

```
var client = require('redis').createClient({
      host : 'redis-dev.amazonaws.com',
      port : 6379,
      no_ready_check: true,
      auth_pass: 'mypassword#c$blx!Na'                                                                                                                                                    
});
```

Error:

```
{ "errorMessage": "2018-06-08T17:55:38.344Z 23a4f9da-6b45-11e8-abe5-6119b1378dff Task timed out after 5.01 seconds"}
```

Any can help me?

Comment: Is the Redis server in the same VPC as the Lambda function? Is the security group assigned to the Redis server configured to allow connections from the Lambda function?

Comment: security is with 0.0.0.0/0 allow all, external applications like spring, are able to connect, but in case of spring for example, in properties there are spring.redis.ssl=true and spring.redis.password="3455"

Comment: A timeout sounds like a network issue, not an authentication issue. You didn't fully answer my question, are the Lambda function and the Redis server in the same VPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message looks like lambda is running in a subnet/vpc which doesn’t have outbound access to the redis server. 
Try one of  2 options to find the root cause

1- try running the code from your local machine and check if you can connect to redis server.

2- remove vpc setting in the lambda to execute lambda outside vpc .

Answer (score 1):

As said by others VPC can be the issue, but there is another thing coming to mind.

Is this timeout a redis connection timeout or Lambda timeout ? Because, redis connections keeps the nodejs loop busy. And Lambda is by default waits for everything to clear up.

If so, try setting
`context.callbackWaitsForEmtpyEventLoop = false` at the function handler. Or before the callback kill the redis connection.